# system() won't accept variables in my wget request

Tags: php, curl, system, wget

I am at my whits end with this. I have finally gotten wget to grab the page I want, how I want it, but I am unable to pass variables in to the system() function in order to loop through all the URLs I want.

Current working wget request:

`system('/usr/local/bin/wget -O wget-files/fda-test.txt "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=AEROSEB%2DDEX" 2>&1');`

What I cannot get to work:

I want to set the file name to $file_name and the requested URL there to $url but everything I try breaks it.

A few things to note, I have tried curl and it does not work due to redirect 302. I have researched Node.js and Phantom along with some other solutions and I am not particularly fond of any of them for this project. Wget works beautifully for this, I simply need to make the request dynamic so I can loop through records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use curl, and follow redirects (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`). much esier

Comment: already did that. curl will not get what i need. wget will every time. curl misses on the redirect even with the followlocation set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

odd about curl however try:

```
system('/usr/local/bin/wget -O wget-files/fda-test.txt '.$file_name.$url' 2>&1');
```

This was what worked after I modified it, but thanks for the dialogue Dragon. -Brent

```
        // Wget the pages
        system('/usr/local/bin/wget -O wget-files/'.$file_name.' "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?'.$source.'" 2>&1');
```

Comment: system('/usr/local/bin/wget -O wget-files/'.$file_name.' "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?'.$source.'" 2>&1'); that actually worked. I just had to play around with the formatting. I have been staring at this code too long! lol thanks Dragon.

Comment: Haha I will even though I pretty much solved it on my own. LOL

Comment: feel free to answer your own question then, i assumed thanking me meant it helped.

Comment: @dragon, dude don't take it the wrong way. obviously it sparked the solution, so thanks (again) and I did mark it. :)